# Format multiple fields to same height

Tags: infopath

Have found very few resources on how to format repeating tables so the date/time/name field is Justified to the top left of the history value. Has anyone found a working method?

I have my fields on Justify which is directed towards the top left on the Table Tools menu.

[image]